# How to represent 5 different options for user while doing signup?

Tags: options, many-options

I am developing a website for mobile and desktop. Users can register through signup form, where they have to select one out of 5 user types. Each type will have a help text for explanation. After selecting user type only, user details form will be shown.

I have tried different variations like providing radio buttons, boxes, etc., but nothing is satisfactory or intuitive.

Can somebody throw some idea for this?

Comment: In order to get good answers here, could you please add a mockup or screenshot of what you have tried, and an explanation *why* you think your solutions are not satisfactory or intuitive?

Comment: What user types? Are you a cook or a food deliverer? Are you a web beginner or expert?

Comment: I agree with @BartGijssens.  How is "Select user type" and then five radio buttons not intuitive?  It seems pretty obvious.  More explanation of the problem is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Why not show the summary first and let the user chose from available options?
Just like the domain hosting sited do? e.g.

[image]